# Netty.io file transfer

Tags: java, networking, netty

As the title says, I want to transfer specific files from client to server using Netty.io. I've tried sending bytes from the client to the server, putting those bytes into an array and then create a file off of them but it did not work. This is the code:

```
@Override
protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf buf) throws IOException {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[buf.readableBytes()];
    buf.readBytes(bytes);
    InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(in);
    System.out.println(image);
    try{
        ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new File("ok.jpg"));
    }catch (Exception ignored){}
```

That never worked though, as *image* would always be null.
I've pretty much tried everything I could find but it's either an outdated code / explanation or bad answers.

So, how would I be able to send a file from the client to the server?

Answer (score 0):

The client side is not given in your example, so difficult to find out the reason.
It might be that the client is not sending anything (no `flush`?).
Also consider that even if you send a full ByteBuf from client side, it does not mean that on receiver side there will be only one ByteBuf due to network splitting into packets.

Maybe you can have a look at the test example using Chunked handler:

https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.1/handler/src/test/java/io/netty/handler/stream/ChunkedWriteHandlerTest.java

and the API:
https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/handler/stream/package-summary.html

Try to add the LoggingHandler in your pipeline on both sides, in order to see what is going on :
https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/e83132fcf2f3ee560826586043ed9a87ef2dcfbf/handler/src/main/java/io/netty/handler/logging/LoggingHandler.java#L42

Comment: The client side works just fine as far as sending the bytes. It's a server side problem.

Comment: Also, would there be a way less tedious than the one shown in the example?

Comment: How do you know the client really send the array of bytes ? (ensure flush on write)
On server side, maybe there are multiple ByteBuf received to form the final array of bytes. Can you just received all data and print the ByteBuf size for each?
And in your pipeline, you can add the LoggingHandler, both on client side and server side to see what is going on... 
https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/e83132fcf2f3ee560826586043ed9a87ef2dcfbf/handler/src/main/java/io/netty/handler/logging/LoggingHandler.java#L42